# App unavailable for ipad wifi only on the appstore

Tags: ios, app-store

I've just noticed that our app is unavailable on the appstore for ipad wifi only.
In compatibility section on the app page i can read : "Available on iphone, ipad 2 Wifi + cellular, iPad Wifi + cellular (3rd generation), etc"
How i can allowed ipad with wifi only to download my app ?

Comment: Does your app use core location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the project's info.plist file, and check for the `Required device capabilities` field. You might have the `gps` and `location-services` keys mentioned there.

The device capabilities field lists the required device features that you app needs on the basis of which it is made available to compatible devices. Read the [Device Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html) section in the documentation.

The above documentation for the `gps` key states:

> Include this key if your app requires (or specifically prohibits) the
>   presence of GPS (or AGPS) hardware when tracking locations. (You
>   should include this key only if you need the higher accuracy offered
>   by GPS hardware.) If you include this key, you should also include the
>   location-services key. **You should require GPS only if your app needs
>   location data more accurate than the cellular or Wi-fi radios might
>   otherwise provide.**

It is on the basis of this key that the application is not made available to devices which do not have a dedicated GPS module (which is built into the cellular module).

If your app can run without super-accurate gps, then you should remove this key.